# Is it true that $|O(2n) - O(n)|=O(n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove or contradict:$$|O(2n) - O(n)|=O(n)$$
I try:
$$\\f(n)=1.5n\in O(2n),g(n)=0.25n\in O(n),h(n)>0\in O(n) : \\
|1.5n - 0.25n|=h(n)\\1.h(n)=1.25n \in O(n)\\
but: 2. h(n)=-1.25n \notin O(n)$$
Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong. $-1.25 n$ is in $O(n)$. Re-check your definition of $O(n)$. It contains absolute values.

Also, it is fairly easy to show that $O(n) = O(2n)$.

Comment: ok,thanks..so how can I prove that?

Comment: Using the definition of $O(n)$ take any function in $O(n)$ and show that it is in $O(2n)$. Then take any function in $O(2n)$ and show that it is in $O(n)$

Answer (score 1):

I think it is correct:
$$
\left| \frac{O(2n)-O(n)}{n} \right| = \left| O(1)-O(1) \right| = O(1).
$$